# .NumberFormat not working on cells using SUMIFS

Tags: excel, vba

I want to format a range of cells using the Indian currency comma separation style, that is formatting the default `123,456,789` into `12,34,56,789`, and I'm using the following code :

```
LastCompoundInterval = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & LastCompoundInterval).Formula = "=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$" & LastTransaction & ",$H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ","">"" & B2, $H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ",""<="" & C2)"
With Range("F2:F" & LastCompoundInterval)
    .NumberFormat = "[>=10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000] ##\,##\,##0;##,##0"
End With
```

The above number format works on other ranges as expected, but the default number format continues to be in use for Range F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a standalone Excel solution, I changed your formula to format it as it is being incorporated into the cell using `TEXT()`.

```
LastCompoundInterval = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & LastCompoundInterval).Formula = "=TEXT(SUMIFS($I$2:$I$" & LastTransaction & ",$H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ","">"" & B2, $H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ",""<="" & C2),""[<=9999999]###,####;###,###,####"")"
```

For a VBA solution, this will help guide you by adding the reference to the workbook / worksheet. Be sure to change "Sheet1" to the name of your worksheet.

```
LastCompoundInterval = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & LastCompoundInterval).Formula = "=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$" & LastTransaction & ",$H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ","">"" & B2, $H$2:$H$" & LastTransaction & ",""<="" & C2)"
With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F" & LastCompoundInterval)
    .NumberFormat = "[>=10000000]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>=100000] ##\,##\,##0;##,##0"
End With
```

Comment: I get a `Compile error: Expected: end of statement` caused by `,` in `""<="" & C2)", "[>=10000000]`

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: It doesn't throw up an error syntax-wise, but... it doesn't work. The format of Range F changes to "General", but it remains comma separated the default way. Furthermore, it messes up other formulas in my worksheet. For example, A3 = `=(A2+E2+F2)` outputs a `#VALUE!` error

Comment: using the excel or vba solution?

Comment: Apologies. The Excel solution

Comment: Updated again :)

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work :/ Quick question, my original code posted in my question, works as intended, but only for the positive values in the range. How do I make it work even for negative values?

Comment: that's probably the reason it doesn't work lol. You could apply a `IFERROR()` to it :)